# Add Member Disabled

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to add new members to my Google Compute Engine project.  However, the "Add Member" button is disabled for some reason.  I am the "owner" of this project.[image]

Any one know how to enable this?

Comment: Is the other member of the project an owner?If so, can he add a new member? Also, did you try to visit the page with the Chrome's incognito window?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the Developer Console using a Google Chrome Incognito window to avoid multiple logins or cookie problems?

Comment: Just tried Incognito mode but same issue.  One other user can "edit".  I'll have him see if he can assign new permissions.  I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Hello, did you managed to add new member?

Comment: I have not been able to add any extra people.  Not sure if its a Google issue or a fixed limit of 2 people?

Comment: No, the limit for normal accounts is 15 and for premier accounts is 50 as per the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/premier/

Comment: Were you able to add a new member? If not, I believe that your project was affected by an issue and my recommendation at this point is to create a new project and delete this one.

Comment: Yes it fixed itself.  I guess Google did something...

Comment: I've got the same problem :-(  Cannot "Add Member" because dimmed out.  Does member have to be in same "Google Apps" account (i.e we have Google Apps free for 10 users (not Business)?

Comment: I just had the same problem, and opened a case with Google. Google's answer was to delete and recreate the project, while refusing to refund our charges so far. How amateur on their side..