# Cannot "Add Member" to a project on Google Developers Console using Google App Account

Tags: google-api-console

I wanted to add team members to the project that I added and I followed the steps from this help page.

https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#differentroles

But when I go to `https://console.developers.google.com/project/<my-project-name>/permissions`, "Add Member" button on the top is disabled.

Here is the link to the screenshot

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_MZvCVsQzrWTmpnNnZBbkZycTg

I used our company's google app account. It seems to work with my personal gmail (non-app) account. Does anyone know why I cannot add members using google app account?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I have similar issue.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850097/add-member-disabled